# How to create a search function using Javascript or Jquery for Bible verse for instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a link of drop down list for the Bible on my webpage, I'm new to this thing. What I want is to do is to be able to select or ask the user to input the verse that they want to go to and then click Submit button then take that to the section of the Bible. For instance, if the user input Mathew 1: 2-10, this should take them to that section of that line of the Bible verse. How do I start doing this? and is Javascript and Jquery even the correct script to use or I need to use other programming language?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to store the Bible text in a data base on a server, then you would need two programming languages: one for the server and one for the client (browser). JavaScript (with or without jQuery) would be a good tool for the client. Alternatives would be ActionScript (Flash) or a Java applet, but I would not recommend either of them for this.

On the server side, it completely depends on the nature of the server. Probably the most common combination is PHP and MySQL, although there are lots of other possibilities. For instance, you could store the data in XML files on the server and use XSLT to format the results for display in HTML on the client. That's the approach taken by [tanach.us](http://tanach.us/) (for the Hebrew Bible).

Answer (score 0):

Intrigued by such a task I was wondering. Yes it can be done, but don't just wave away @Ted his comment. It will indeed be a better option to choose for a database application.
But yes, if you don't mind the work and just use it on a small scale, it is possible to create a javascript based application to serve your pages.

You could use an iframe to serve your pages. With creating a selection box that populates a second one, it is possible to make an acceptable application. The pages are collected in javascript objects and served. In this example the domain of w3schools is used.

```
var Mathew = {
     verses: ["verse2_1", "verse2_2", "verse2_3"],
     verse2_1: "html/html_iframe.asp",
     verse2_2: "tags/tag_select.asp",
     verse2_3: "jquery/default.asp"
 }
```

The first selection box will contain a hand coded option list

```
<select name="book" id="book">
    <option value="choose">Please choose</option>
    <option value="Mathew">Mathew</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
</select>
```

The second option list is automatically populated with the help of the javascript object.

```
function populateSecondSelect(book) {
    if (book == "choose") {
        $("#verses").children().remove();
        $("#verses").append("<option>choose a book first</option>");
        $("button").prop("disabled", true);
        return;
    }

    $("button").prop("disabled", false);
    var obj = eval(book);
    $("#verses").children().remove();
    $(obj.verses).each(function () {
        $("<option/>", {
            name: this,
            id: this,
            value: this,
            text: this
        }).appendTo("#verses");
    });
}
```

With the second selection made, the button can be clicked to serve the page:

```
function fetchVerse() {
    var book = $("#book").val();
    var verse = $("#verses").val();
    var url = baseUrl + eval(book + "." + verse);
    $("#frame").attr("src", url);
}
```

The whole thing is working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/nEqeK/4/

It is fun, but a database for a whole bible is better ..